# My pagination is jumping around and I can't figure out how to fix it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I'm making a product listings page that uses AJAX calls to post the user's inputted data:

- The pagination uses the jQuery inView function to call the next page
  (*NextPage.php*) when `loader.gif` is in view

  **InfiniteScroll.js**

```
      $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#Loader').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {

                if (isInView) {

                //Pagination
                var nextPage = parseInt($('#pageno').val()) + 1;

                    //Filters
                    var minimum_wt = $('#hidden_minimum_wt').val();
                    var maximum_wt = $('#hidden_maximum_wt').val();
                    var shape = get_filter('shape');
                    var color = get_filter('color');
                    var enhancement = get_filter('enhancement');
                    var matching = get_filter('matching');

                    $.ajax({

                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'vendors/php/NextPage.php',
                        data: {
                            pageno: nextPage,
                            minimum_wt: minimum_wt,
                            maximum_wt: maximum_wt,
                            shape: shape,
                            color: color,
                            enhancement: enhancement,
                            matching: matching
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {

                            console.log(nextPage); //For debugging

                            if(data != '') {
                                $('#StoneContainer').append(data);
                                $('#pageno').val(nextPage);
                            } else {
                                $('.LoaderContainer').hide();   //Hide infinite scroll
                            }

                        }

                    });

                }

            });

        });


        //Checking applied filters
        function get_filter(class_name) {

            var filter = [];

            $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function() {
                filter.push($(this).val());
            });

            return filter;

        }
```

**NextPage.php**

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['pageno']) || isset($_POST['action'])) {
        $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
    } else {
        $pageno = $_POST['pageno'];
    }

    $limit = 10;
    $offset = ($pageno-1) * $limit;

    //Include database configuration file
    include('dbConfig.php');

    $SQL = "        
        SELECT
            number,
            image1,
            wt,
            TRUNCATE(length,1) as length,
            TRUNCATE(width,1) as width,
            CASE
                WHEN stonetype = 'SA' THEN 'Sapphire'
                WHEN stonetype = 'RU' THEN 'Ruby'
                WHEN stonetype = 'TML-P' THEN 'Paraiba'
                WHEN stonetype = 'EM' THEN 'Emerald'
                WHEN stonetype = 'TS' THEN 'Tsavorite'
                WHEN stonetype = 'SI' THEN 'Spinel'
                WHEN stonetype = 'GT' THEN 'Garnet'
                WHEN stonetype = 'BER' THEN 'Beryl'
                WHEN stonetype = 'TML' THEN 'Tourmaline'
                WHEN stonetype = 'KO' THEN 'Kornerupine'
                ELSE 'n/a'
            END AS 'stonetype',
            CASE                                    
                WHEN enhcode = 'H' THEN 'Heated'
                WHEN enhcode = 'N' THEN 'Unheated'
                ELSE 'n/a'
            END AS 'enhcode'
        FROM 
            stones
        WHERE 
            wt >= 2.5
    ";

    if(isset($_POST["minimum_wt"], $_POST["maximum_wt"]) && !empty($_POST["minimum_wt"]) && !empty($_POST["maximum_wt"])) {

        $SQL .= "

            AND wt BETWEEN '".$_POST["minimum_wt"]."' AND '".$_POST["maximum_wt"]."'

        ";
    }

    if(isset($_POST["shape"])) {

        $shape_filter = implode("','", $_POST["shape"]);

        $SQL .= "

            AND stoneshape IN('".$shape_filter."') 

        ";

    }

    if(isset($_POST["color"])) {

        $color_filter = implode("','", $_POST["color"]);

        $SQL .= "

            AND stonecolor IN('".$color_filter."')

        ";

    }

    if(isset($_POST["enhancement"])) {

        $enhancement_filter = implode("','", $_POST["enhancement"]);

        $SQL .= "

            AND enhcode IN('".$enhancement_filter."')

        ";

    }

    if(isset($_POST["matching"])) {

        $matching_filter = implode("','", $_POST["matching"]);

        $SQL .= "

            AND pair IN('".$matching_filter."')

        ";  

    }

    $SQL .= " 
        ORDER BY
            wt ASC
        LIMIT
            " . $offset. ",
            " . $limit. "

    ";

    $res_data = mysqli_query($db, $SQL);

    if(isset($_POST["minimum_wt"], $_POST["maximum_wt"]) && !empty($_POST["minimum_wt"]) && !empty($_POST["maximum_wt"]) && isset($_POST["shape"]) && isset($_POST["color"]) && isset($_POST["enhancement"]) && isset($_POST["matching"])) {

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)) {

            echo '  

            <div class="Stone">

                <!-- landing page -->
                <a href="#ItemPage" class="ItemLink" rel="modal:open" id="' . $row['number']. '">

                    <!-- image -->
                    <div class="StoneData StoneIMG"> <img src="../../../' . $row['image1'] . '"> </div>

                    <!-- weight --> 
                    <div class="StoneData">' . $row['wt'] . 'Ct</div>

                    <!-- type -->
                    <div class="StoneData">' . $row['stonetype'] . '</div>

                    <!-- enhancement -->
                    <div class="StoneData">' . $row['enhcode'] . '</div>

                    <!-- dimensions -->
                    <div class="StoneData">' . $row['length'] . ' x ' . $row['width'] . '</div>

                    <!-- item number -->
                    <div class="StoneData"># ' . $row['number'] . '</div>

                </a>

            </div>
            ';

        }

    }

?>
```

- 4 different check box fields and a jQuery range slider so the user
  can filter out only the data they want

**Filters.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    filter_data();

    function filter_data() {

        var action = 'fetch_data';

        //Pagination
        var nextPage = parseInt($('#pageno').val()) + 0;

        //Filters
        var minimum_wt = $('#hidden_minimum_wt').val();
        var maximum_wt = $('#hidden_maximum_wt').val();
        var shape = get_filter('shape');
        var color = get_filter('color');
        var enhancement = get_filter('enhancement');
        var matching = get_filter('matching');

        $.ajax( {

            url: 'vendors/php/Filters/FilterData.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: action, 
                pageno: nextPage,
                minimum_wt: minimum_wt, 
                maximum_wt: maximum_wt, 
                shape: shape, 
                color: color, 
                enhancement: enhancement, 
                matching: matching
            },
            async: true,
            error: 

                function(jqXHR, strError) {

                    if(strError == 'timeout') {

                        // Do something. Try again perhaps?
                        alert('Seems like there was an error loading the filters request.');

                    }

                },

            success:
                function(data) {

                    $('#StoneContainer').html(data);
                    $('#pageno').val(nextPage); 
                    $('.LoaderContainer').show();   //Show infinite scroll  

                },

            timeout: 3000

        });

    }

    // Where to find values to be filtered
    function get_filter(class_name) {

        var filter = [];

        $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function() {
            filter.push($(this).val());
        });

        return filter;

    }

    // Apply filter_data() of .common_selector
    $('.common_selector').click(function() {

        filter_data();

    });

    // Range slider
    $('#wt_range').slider({

        range: true,
        values: [2.5, 30],
        min: 2.5,
        max: 30,
        step: 0.1,
        slide: 
            function(event, ui) {

                // prevent thumbs from overlapping 
                if ((ui.values[1] - ui.values[0]) < 3) {

                    return false;

                }

                $('#wt_show').html(ui.values[0] + 'Ct - ' + ui.values[1] + 'Ct');
                $('#hidden_minimum_wt').val(ui.values[0]);
                $('#hidden_maximum_wt').val(ui.values[1]);

                filter_data();

            }

    });

    // open and close filters menu on mobile
    if ($('#StoneContainer').width() < 420 ) {

        $('.OpenCloseFilters').on('click', function() {

            $('.FiltersContainer').slideToggle();

            // refresh button
            $('.ResetFiltersToggle0').toggleClass('ResetFiltersToggle1');

            // change icon on toggle 
            $('#MenuIcon').toggleClass('mdi-menu-up mdi-menu-down');

        });

    }

});
```

**FilterData.php**

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['pageno']) || isset($_POST['action'])) {

        //Include database configuration file
        include('../dbConfig.php'); 

        $limit = 10;    
        $offset = !empty($_POST['pageno']) ? $_POST['pageno']: 0;

        $SQL = "

            SELECT
                number,
                image1,
                wt,
                TRUNCATE(length,1) as length,
                TRUNCATE(width,1) as width,
                CASE
                    WHEN stonetype = 'SA' THEN 'Sapphire'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'RU' THEN 'Ruby'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'TML-P' THEN 'Paraiba'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'EM' THEN 'Emerald'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'TS' THEN 'Tsavorite'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'SI' THEN 'Spinel'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'GT' THEN 'Garnet'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'BER' THEN 'Beryl'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'TML' THEN 'Tourmaline'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'KO' THEN 'Kornerupine'
                    ELSE 'n/a'
                END AS 'stonetype',
                CASE                                    
                    WHEN enhcode = 'H' THEN 'Heated'
                    WHEN enhcode = 'N' THEN 'Unheated'
                    ELSE 'n/a'
                END AS 'enhcode'
            FROM 
                stones
            WHERE 
                wt >= 2.5

        ";

        if(isset($_POST["minimum_wt"], $_POST["maximum_wt"]) && !empty($_POST["minimum_wt"]) && !empty($_POST["maximum_wt"])) {

            $SQL .= "

                AND wt BETWEEN '".$_POST["minimum_wt"]."' AND '".$_POST["maximum_wt"]."'

            ";

        }

        if(isset($_POST["shape"])) {

            $shape_filter = implode("','", $_POST["shape"]);

            $SQL .= "

                AND stoneshape IN('".$shape_filter."') 

            ";
        }

        if(isset($_POST["color"])) {

            $color_filter = implode("','", $_POST["color"]);

            $SQL .= "

                AND stonecolor IN('".$color_filter."')

            ";

        }

        if(isset($_POST["enhancement"])) {

            $enhancement_filter = implode("','", $_POST["enhancement"]);

            $SQL .= "

                AND enhcode IN('".$enhancement_filter."')

            ";

        }

        if(isset($_POST["matching"])) {

            $matching_filter = implode("','", $_POST["matching"]);

            $SQL .= "

                AND pair IN('".$matching_filter."')

            ";  

        }

        $SQL .= "

            ORDER BY wt ASC
            LIMIT 
                $offset,
                $limit

        ";

        $result = mysqli_query($db, $SQL);

        $output = '';

        if(isset($_POST["minimum_wt"], $_POST["maximum_wt"]) && !empty($_POST["minimum_wt"]) && !empty($_POST["maximum_wt"]) && isset($_POST["shape"]) && isset($_POST["color"]) && isset($_POST["enhancement"]) && isset($_POST["matching"])) {

            if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                foreach($result as $row) {

                    $output .= '

                        <div class="Stone">

                            <!-- landing page -->
                            <a href="#ItemPage" class="ItemLink" rel="modal:open" id="' . $row['number']. '">

                                <!-- image -->
                                <div class="StoneData StoneIMG"> <img src="../../../' . $row['image1'] . '"> </div>

                                <!-- weight --> 
                                <div class="StoneData">' . $row['wt'] . 'Ct</div>

                                <!-- type -->
                                <div class="StoneData">' . $row['stonetype'] . '</div>

                                <!-- enhancement -->
                                <div class="StoneData">' . $row['enhcode'] . '</div>

                                <!-- dimensions -->
                                <div class="StoneData">' . $row['length'] . ' x ' . $row['width'] . '</div>

                                <!-- item number -->
                                <div class="StoneData"># ' . $row['number'] . '</div>

                            </a>

                        </div>

                    ';

                }

            }

        } else {

            $output = '

                <h1 class="Error">
                    <span class="mdi mdi-filter-remove mdi-48px"></span> 
                    NO STONES MATCH THAT
                </h1>

            ';

        }

        echo $output;
    }

?>
```

My problem is when the user updates the filters my pagination jumps to the next page so not only will they not see the else statement on *FilterData.php* (which can obviously be very confusing for the user) but they will get a totally blank page, even when there are some results.

I imagine the solution to be resetting to the first page (of my pagination) every time the data updates. But for some reason I can't figure out how to do it. I tried changing line 52 of *Filters.js* to `$('#pageno').val(0);`, but that didn't seem to work as expected.

I know this is probably a very simple issue for you guys and i'm sort of embarrassed even asking but I've been trying to fix this since last Wednesday and still can't get it (i'm pretty new to php). **Thank you so much for your time in advance!**

Comment: Why 2 you have 2 Javascripts and 2 PHP to do the same thing on both? You need to simplify and include some conditionals, so you can use just 1 Javascript and 1 PHP for both actions, you could have more control and code would be easier to mantain.

Comment: I was thinking this is probably the origin of my issue. I initially started segmenting my code to keep my thoughts together because I was working on one feature a week. Now I have this issue with my pagination.

Comment: I guess you can try right now changing this `var nextPage = parseInt($('#pageno').val()) + 0;` for `var nextPage = 0; $('#pageno').val(0);` in filter_data function.

Comment: This seemed to work; i'm genuinely humiliated. THANKS! 

I'd check this as answered